# How to detect changes to a property of a core data object

Tags: swiftui

I have this core data entity called `Cake`, that has properties like:

- numberOfIngredientsBeingUsed
- numberOfIngredientsTotal
- color
- weight

I read one object from the entity and now I have something like this

```
let orangeCake = Cake(type:"orange", context:coreDataContext)
```

Now I want to show a `ProgressView`. I want to pass the progress view, a binding `numberOfIngredientsBeingUsed` property, representing the current number of ingredients so far being used and a regular property `numberOfIngredientsTotal`, representing the total number of ingredients required to make the cake.

The idea is that when `numberOfIngredientsBeingUsed` changes on the main view, the progress view updates, because it is a binding property.

How do I do that? I cannot wrap my brain around, because `numberOfIngredientsBeingUsed` is a property of the cake object `orangeCake`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CoreData managed objects are type of `ObservableObject`, so instead of passing one property you need to inject entire instance of `Cake` as `ObservedObject` and use its properties inside `ProgressView`, which will update (and refresh view) whenever corresponding object updated somewhere in other part of code.

So it should look like

```
struct ProgressView: View {
   @ObservedObject var model: Cake

   var body: some View {
      Text("Progress: \(model.numberOfIngredientsBeingUsed) of \(model.numberOfIngredientsTotal)")
   }
}
```